# Complexifying a Real Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm preparing for some exams by studying previous exams and I think I have a solution but a few steps may be invalid.

"Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension $d > 2$. Let $T$ be a finite order automorphism. Prove that the associated linear operator

$$T_2: \bigwedge^2V \to \bigwedge^2V, \; v \wedge w \mapsto Tv \wedge Tw$$

fixes a nonzero vector."

Since $T$ has finite order, $T^n = I$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, the minimal polynomial of $T$, call it $m_T$ divides $x^n-1$. This tells us firstly that the eigenvalues of $T$ are $n$th roots of unity over $\mathbb{C}$ and that the minimal polynomial is square free. This implies $T$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Since $T$ is a real linear operator, its characteristic polynomial is real and so the eigenvalues must come in conjugate pairs (and also be norm 1 from the above reasoning). Thus, choose $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ with associated eigenvectors $v, w$, respectively. We have that in the complexified vector space, $T_2(v \wedge w) = \lambda v \wedge \bar{\lambda} w = |\lambda|^2 v \wedge w = v \wedge w$.

Now, I'll like to say that $w = \bar{v}$; we define this by considering that $V$ is finite dimensional and so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the complexification is $\mathbb{R}^d \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^d$. Then, we can do the natural thing of splitting vectors into their real and imaginary parts: $v = v_1 + i v_2$ and define $\bar{v} = v_1 - i v_2$.

Is it the case that $w = \bar{v}$? It seems like if we let $A$ be a matrix representing $T$ given some basis in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then it has real entries and $\overline{A v} = \overline{\lambda v} = \bar{\lambda} \bar{v} = A \bar{v}$. The final equality comes as $A$ has real entries so conjugation shouldn't affect it.

Even if we can do this, $v \wedge \bar{v}$ isn't necessarily in our original space $V$. I suppose we can say

$$v \wedge \bar{v} = (v_1 + i v_2) \wedge (v_1 - i v_2) = v_1 \wedge v_1 -2iv_1 \wedge v_2 + v_2 \wedge v_2 = -2i v_1 \wedge v_2.$$

The last equality comes because $v_1 \wedge v_1 = v_2 \wedge v_2 = 0$.
Then take

$$T_2 (v_1 \wedge v_2) = T_2(-\frac{1}{2i} v \wedge \bar{v}) = -\frac{1}{2i} T v \wedge T \bar{v} = -\frac{\lambda \bar{\lambda}}{2i} v \wedge \bar{v} = v_1 \wedge v_2.$$

If I've made any mistakes, please let me know.